# mysql join in another join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

t1:

```
id | t2_connect
-----------------
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 2
```

t2:

```
id | t3_connect
-----------------
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 1
```

t3

```
id | goal
-----------------
1  | 10
2  | 100
3  | 1000
```

and I want to select goal values through t2 table
something like:

```
SELECT 
t1.id, t3.goal
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON (t2.id=t1.t2_connect)
JOIN t3 ON (t3.id=t2.t3_connect)
WHERE 1
```

But it is not working.(Error: Unknown column 't2.t3_connect' in 'on clause' ) Can you please help me with that.
I expect:

```
t1.id | t3.goal
-----------------
1  | 1000
2  | 10
3  | 1000
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the expected result?

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means.

Comment: Besides your WHERE 1 , the query seems correct.. what do you expect to get? I'll suggest to delete the where clause

Comment: Maybe you meant to `order by 1` (T1.ID?) instead of `where 1`?  If that's the case I'd rather `order by t1.id` it's easier to read./maintain

Comment: I just edited it. Hope it clear now.

Comment: I just set up your test tables and used your SQL and it worked fine and returned the results you want (except for the order - but no order is specified).

Comment: Just delete the WHERE and you're fine.